# Is /testfor more efficient

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm creating a survival map, and I'm using a scoreboard value `hearts` to determine how many extra heart levels the player should have.

I'm using `/testfor @a[score_hearts=1,score_hearts_min=1]`, if true then triggers
`/effect @a[score_hearts=1,score_hearts_min=1] minecraft:health_boost 5 1 true` in conditional command block. (Repeating with other values up to 10)

What I noticed is that I could just use the `/effect` command on it's own in a repeating command block. My question is, is it more efficient (ie. causes less lag) to only use `/effect` in it's own command block and ommit `/testfor`, or is there some reason why using `/testfor` would be more efficient (More optimized code?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You definitely don't need to be using `testfor` here.  The only reason you might want to use `testfor` before conditionally running something like `effect` is if you wanted to test for something that can't be tested in a selector, i.e. NBT data, and even then, that would be such a narrow case that you're better off putting that test in a scoreboard.  Since you're applying the `effect` against a selector already, the `testfor` is basically doing nothing for you; either the `testfor` succeeds and you run 2 commands, or it fails and you run only 1, whereas without it, you run 1 command, or half a command.  If you don't have a lot of commands, you're not going to see a performance difference though.

But this belies another issue, which is `testfor` is only marginally useful right now, but will be going away in 1.13, replaced with a new and improved `execute` command.

In the end though, my rule of thumb is to only use `testfor` if it results in the fewest command blocks, and almost never if chained conditional command blocks target players (or entities in general) instead of the world.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't. The target selector is the first part of your `/effect` command that gets evaluated. If that returns no entities, the rest of the command doesn't run.

If you wanted to count entities, a testfor command would actually be better, because `/testfor` only queries a number, `/execute` or other commands query entities (which are a lot more to load than just one number), but if you want to either do nothing in the case of 0 entities or do something with all entities if there are some, you don't need `/testfor`.